# Angular pagination with data sent from backend

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pagination

I must have a pagination in my table, and the backend already brings me how much data I can show, but I don't know how to apply it to the pagination.

What is marked in red is how I should add them to the table so that the data is loaded.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNVKO.png)

and in html I don't know how to make it work.

```
<mat-paginator length="pagLenght" [pageSize]="10"
                aria-label="Select page" >
            </mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check out ngx-pagination? its probably the simplest i have used.

Your template

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>

    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

Make sure you import in your App Module and declare variable "p" which is the page tracker in your component.

Let me know if it works for you. Cheers